# Enabling Change Logs in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server

I am very new to SQL Server database. We have installed SQL Server 2016. We would like to enable the change logs with maximum retention of 14 days. The purpose is to track any changes done etc.

Can someone please help me out with the steps to achieve this?

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: Agreed - voting to move as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome, Ayushi.

Based on your question, it appears that you want to have an easy ability to look at what has changed in the last 14 days. If this is the case, then you are probably looking at enabling Change Data Capture (CDC).

(*Note: To ensure that you actually want CDC, and not just Change Tracking, you should read [this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/track-data-changes-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)*)

Unfortunately, this is more than a simple "flip this switch to track changes" answer. To implement this, you can start with [this article on implementing the different types of change tracking from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/track-data-changes-sql-server?view=sql-server-2016), and then go to the subarticles on actual implementation, space considerations, etc.

Note that you may only want to track changes on a few tables, and not the entire database, for space and performance reasons.